# can't find .ssh directory after user creation in ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

After creating a user(spider), I am trying to copy the contents of of .ssh/authorized_keys of another user (butterfly) to the .ssh/ of user (spider). Below are the commands

cp ~butterfly/.ssh/authorized_keys ~spider/.ssh/

But I am getting the error as
Cannot create regular file .ssh. Not a directory.

So it is not able to find the .ssh directory. When i am running the ls -altr ~butterfly/
it still doesnt find the directory.
wheras I can see the directory from the terminal.
I do not see any permission issue as it is accessible as root as well.

The ls -altr ~butterfly/ in ansible lists out the files and directories but from an older timestamp.
Can someone please help me to figure out what is happening here

This is a shellscript which is being executed by Ansible

Comment: maybe use install -d to create dir with proper owner and permissions

Comment: Does .ssh directory exist for spider?

Comment: @stark I am using -d while creating the user

Comment: @Rickkwa .ssh directory exists. but it doesnt gets listed when I do ls -altr for that users home directory (spider)

Comment: Hmm, does ~username resolve properly in the script? Dunno if you want to try using absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Most distributions do not create the `.ssh` directory in user's home by default when you create a user. Moreover, copying the file from an other user's `authorized_keys` with your above command will fail on connection attempt as the file will not have the correct permissions. Last, you can do much better with ansible.

The below example will:

- get the `authorized_keys` file content from `user1`
- create `user2` if it does not exist
- create the `.ssh` dir and set its permissions correctly if needed
- create each key from `user1` for `user2` if it does not already exist. Other existing keys in the users's file if any will be kept untouched (see bottom of this post if this is unwanted).

```yaml
---
- name: copy authorized keys from user1 to user2
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Get authorized_keys file from user1
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
      become: true
      register: user1_authorized_keys

    - name: Create user2 if it does not exist
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: user2
        create_home: true
        state: present
      become: true

    - name: copy keys from user1 to user2
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: user2
        manage_dir: true
        key: "{{ user1_authorized_keys.content | b64decode }}"
        state: present
      become: true
```

This gives on first run (with `user2` not created):

```
PLAY [copy authorized keys from user1 to user2] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get authorized_keys file from user1] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testhost]

TASK [Create user2 if it does not exist] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [testhost]

TASK [copy keys from user1 to user2] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [testhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
testhost                   : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and on second run (to demonstrate idempotency with `changed=0` below)

```
PLAY [copy authorized keys from user1 to user2] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get authorized_keys file from user1] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testhost]

TASK [Create user2 if it does not exist] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testhost]

TASK [copy keys from user1 to user2] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [testhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
testhost                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Note that if your goal is to systematically replace the keys for `user2` with the ones from `user1` (i.e. delete any previous existing keys if any), you simply have to add the `exclusive:` option to the corresponding task:

```yaml
    - name: copy keys from user1 to user2
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: user2
        manage_dir: true
        key: "{{ user1_authorized_keys.content | b64decode }}"
        exclusive: true
        state: present
      become: true
```

References:

- [`slurp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html)
- [`user` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html)
- [`authorized_key` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering this. It doesn't give any permission issue. Because I am able to access the .ssh directory through terminal. But when i try to list out via shellscript, it doesnt find it. Bot are executed as root user.
moreover it lists the contents of users home directory for a different time stamp.
and I want to use the shell script to perform the above action and the shell script is being called via ansible. This is a part of the configuration script.

Comment: I suspect that if you run my above playbook, you'll find out that the .ssh dir is created. There is no such thing as not being able to acces a directory you have permission for or listing the content from a "different timestamp". A dir exists with it's permissions in a filesystem or does not.  If you see it in your terminal but not when running your script, you are targeting different filesystems in each situation (and possibly different hosts...)